# Prevent Visual Studio 2019 from starting debugged desktop application on focused monitor

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2019

When I start debugging the application, it will be started on the monitor that is focused / where my mouse is at. I would like to have it at the same place every time.

I was unable to find a Visual Studio, Resharper or Windows 10 setting.
Probably I could add some debug only code for the position, but I would like to have more general solution - especially as my floating windows have a chance to move as well and I think it is related.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is the [WindowStartupLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.windowstartuplocation?view=net-5.0)=CenterScreen defined in the XAML of the window.  So it had nothing to do with the components I suspected. And removing it did not resolve the issue with the floating windows :/

```
<Window WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"/>
```